# Block class is not getting loaded in magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, crud

I created a simple layout where I specify the block class and the template to be rendered. But it seems like the block and template is not getting rendered. Below is the code. I am trying the CRUD models implementation in magento. I have successfully created the table via the InstallSchema.php. Also, when I var_dump in the controller the data is displayed perfectly. The problem arises when I try to divert it via the block.

routes.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="crud" id="crud">
            <module name="Mathanagopal_CRUD"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Controller/Index/Index.php

```php
<?php
namespace Mathanagopal\CRUD\Controller\Index;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $_pageFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
        ) {
            $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
            return parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute()
        {
            return $this->_pageFactory->create();
        }
    }
```

crud_index_index.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Mathanagopal\CRUD\Block\Index"
               name="crud_index_index"
               template="Mathanagopal_CRUD::index.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Block/Index.php

```php
<?php
namespace Mathanagopal\CRUD\Block;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {

        protected $_postFactory;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Mathanagopal\CRUD\Model\PostFactory $postFactory
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->_postFactory = $postFactory;
        }

        public function getResult()
        {
            $post = $this->_postFactory->create();
            return $post->getCollection();
        }
    }
```

index.phtml

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
        <th>Updated At</th>
        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
        /** @var \Mathanagopal\CRUD\Block\Index $block */
        $collection = $block->getResult();
        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $item->getData('post_id'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->getDate('name'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->getData('created_at'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $item->getData('updated_at'); ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('crud/index/edit') . 'id/' . $item->getData('post_id'); ?>" class="action primary">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('crud/index/delete') . '?id=' . $item->getData('post_id'); ?>" class="action primary">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        } ?>
</table>
```

This is the output. [go to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3U19.png).

Comment: Pls check is any logs, seems you have syntax error somewhere in your code. to check just add static text in your template file and run that Url.

Comment: Whats is the full path of `crud_index_index.xml`

Comment: @prince view/frontend/layout/crud_index_index.xml

Comment: @jafar pinjar I will check.